# Vue force all children components to render

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, vuetify.js

I’m using Vue & Vuetify to create my app. With vuetify I’m using `v-expansion-panels` to create an accordion style display. Each `v-expansion-panel` itself contains a custom component.

I have noticed these components **are not created** until the expansion panel is clicked for the first time. After that, using `keep-alive` allows all reactive properties and methods of the child component to be active (this is my desired behavior).

How can I force the child components to be created when the parent is created? This, any method triggered in the `created()` lifecycle hook of a child component should fire when the parent is created.

[This Codepen](https://codepen.io/hanzymusic/pen/YzKvgxJ?editors=1111) is an example of the current behavior.  Note: be sure to look at the console when you click the panel.

Answer (score 1):

If you think about it, it actually makes sense to lazy load content of expansion panels since it is useless work if the user never opens them anyway. So probably the thing you try to accomplish has some better approach, but if you still like it then my advice is to find a way of programatically opening / closing the panel (as seen [here](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/wPvoyx?editors=1010)) and quickly open it and close it when rendering parent component. In this way, you will have your child component `created` and the UI will remain the same.

Answer (score 0):

A Vuetify solution should be achievable by adding the [eager](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/api/v-dialog/) prop to a `v-expansion-panel-content` element in the Expansion Panel. This should force any components or content contained within the `v-expansion-panel-content` element to render on mounted.

```html
<v-expansion-panels v-model="panels">
  <v-expansion-panel>
    <v-expansion-panel-content eager>
      <custom-component />
    </v-expansion-panel-content>
  </v-expansion-panel>
</v-expansion-panels>
```